# SaveAsync not working with outlook new webui

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have recently come across an issue with the new UI of outlook 365 which is in trial stage at the moment. In my outlook addin we are using saveAsync method of officeapi, I found that when we are in new UI,  SaveAsync method return null instead of ItemID.

However same code works with the existing UI without any issue and works as expected.

Has somebody came across this issue or know if there is any plan to fix it.

This issue happens on calendar appointment on new ui and it consistently  returns null.

here is the code snippet
callSaveAsync();

```
var callSaveAsync = function() {
        office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(data) {
            logMessage("saveAsync complete - call number " + asyncCount);
            logMessage("ID returned: " + data.value);
            if (data.value === null) {
                asyncCount++;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callSaveAsync();
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                logMessage("ID success.", true);
                asyncCount = 1;
                itemID = data.value;
                callGetItem(itemID);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: We could not repro this issue on our end. Can you provide the code snippet you are using for this purpose? Does this issue happen all the time in new UI or you can get the item ID sometimes? Does this issue repro for a New Mail or on Reply to existing email?

Comment: i have edited my original post and updated my response there

Comment: Hi  Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT,  were you able to replicate by using the steps i mentioned

Comment: We could not repro the issue with code snippet you shared. Which browser and OS you are trying this on? Does this issue repro for a New Mail or on Reply to existing email?

Comment: Hi Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, in order to reproduce try with calendar appointments.

Comment: Yes, we tried repro with calendar appointment and could not reproduce this inhouse. Can you also try same test with "New Email" and "Reply to an existing email"? Does this work as expected for you?

Comment: Also, could you please share email id of the account with us?

Comment: Hi, which account ? is it outlook account you are asking for? Also, i am not sure if email actually relevant in our scenario as we do not have any addin for mails, our addin mainly deals with Calendar appointments

Comment: 1.Yes, email/calendar outlook account you are using.
2.We are still not able to repro this in calendar appointments: 
`var callSaveAsync = function() {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync
  (
   function(data) {
               if (data.value === null) {
                 showMessage("Error");
               } else {
                   showMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
                  itemID = data.value;
               }
   }
  );
};
callSaveAsync();
`3.Can you also try same test with "New Email" and "Reply to an existing email"? Does this work as expected for you?

Comment: Hi There, just tried again today and it seems like its fixed now and getting the expected results. Seems like some updates have done the trick, but i definitely had this issue. Thanks outlook-add-ins-team-msft